# Convolutional codes: free distance (Part 2)

Tags: solution-verification, coding-theory

This is a follow-up question of [convolutional codes: free distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4765486/235690), and is meant to confirm a counter-example to it:

Specifically, if we terminate a convolutional code in some non-zero state, then the free distance is, in general, **not** the minimum distance between the all-zero path and some other non-all-zero path, starting and ending in the zero state, is it?

For example, suppose we have a ($n=2, k=1, K=3$) conv. code with the parity check generators being [1 0 1] and [1 0 0], as illustrated below.  (Note that the code has 4 states.)  Suppose (somewhat pathologically) that we start the code in state '00', take 2 information bits, and then force the state machine to state '11' with 2 tail bits '11'.  Then effectively we have a block code of length 8.  (Rate is 1/4, instead of 1/2, due to the forced 2 tail bits.)

[image]

For this code, aren't the following true?

- This is a non-linear block code, which does not even contain the all zero path ('00000000').
- The free distance of this code is **not** the minimum distance of between the all-zero path and some non-all-zero path ending in the zero state.

In fact, it's easily verified that the code simply consists of 4 codewords: 00001111, 00111101, 11000111, 11110101.  The minimum weight of the code is 4, but the free distance is 3.  The free distance occurs between, for instance, the 2 paths starting in state 00 and ending in state 10, i.e. '000011' and '110001'.

Comment: Rpeating my point. There is no such thing as *the free distance of a block code*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I appreciate your comments here and in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4767607/235690.  I did some more investigation.  It has a long winding history.  The term first appeared in 1969, proposed by Costello.  As you said, many authors subsequently used the term in different problems/scenarios, each of which had its, sometimes implicit, assumptions.  That's why I got confused.

Comment: When I have some more time, I'll try to summarize them and see if it can be further clarified, just in case someone else has similar confusion in days to come.