# Convolutional codes: free distance (Part 3)

Tags: solution-verification, coding-theory

This is a follow-up question of [convolutional codes: free distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4765486/235690) and
[Convolutional codes: free distance (Part II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4767098/235690), and is to confirm the following conjecture:

A convolutional code with "direct truncation" (i.e. without forcing tail bits) is a linear block code, but its free distance is in general **not** the minimum distance between the all-zero-path and some other non-all-zero path, originating and ending in the zero state, either. (?)

Here's a simple example:

Consider a (n=2,k=1,K=3) conv. code with the parity check generators being [1 1 0] and [1 1 1]. We start the code in state '00', take 3 information bits, and stop the state machine right there.
[image]
For this code, it's easy to verify:

- This is a linear code of length 6, rate 1/2.
- The free distance of the code is 2, and
- is the weight of the '000011' codeword, derived from the following state transitions: 00, 00, 00, 10, as illustrated in blue above.
- The only non-all-zero path starting and ending in state 00 gives the '111101' codeword, whose weight is 5, as illustrated in red.

Hence the free distance is **not** the minimum distance between the all-zero-path and some other non-all-zero path starting and ending in the zero state.  If I'm mistaken somewhere, I'd greatly appreciate your corrections/comments.

Comment: The convention I use when teaching this topic is that *free distance of a convolutional code* always counts terminating bits, and does not constrain the length of the input sequence. I'm well aware that in practical applications we often need to truncate the terminating bits (or arrange a situation where the encoder starts and ends at the same state). As you observed, brutally terminated codes become block codes, and we can use normal block code terminology to describe their parameters. Many authors may use different terminology as they see fit - I'm not an authority on this theme.

Comment: Anyway, you describe a convolutional code with generator matrix $(1+D, 1+D+D^2)$. I would say that the free distance of this code is four, corresponding for example to the input $u(D)=1+D$ and the codeword $(1+D^2,1+D^3)$. I would not use the term *free distance* at all when discussing non-terminated output sequences, because I don't see the point. You will always have very low weight outputs if you exit the zero state at the last minute and then immediately truncate. That does not say much about the error-correcting capability of the code.

Comment: Agree with @JyrkiLahtonen, you are kind of making up your own definitions. But like him, convolutional codes is not where my deep expertise is.